# Manage different base templates from database in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, templates

I'm trying to manage multiple templates in  Symfony. The active Template comes from a database and I have a controller which gives the correct path entry.

My Problem is to tell symfony about this path. I have searched the Twig render method in multiple classes but changes are not successfully.

My TemplateController.php

```
public function loadtpl() {

    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Templates::class);
    $found = $repo->findByActive(1);
    $tpl = $found[0]->getPath();
    return $tpl;

}
```

This gives me the template path but I find no way to tell symfony about it.

UPDATE:

**What I have** - 2 different layouts located in templates/layout1 and template/layout2

**What I get** - my TemplateController (above) returns the active layout path (layout1/)

Now I can edit my twig.yaml to say twig my template path to ../templates/layout1 so I can use `render(mysite.html.twig);` which is located in layout1 (and layout2) but its not what I want.

**What I want** - I want  to extend the base template path dynamically with my layout paths so that I can use the method render (mysite.html.twig) without editing twig.yaml manually.

**What I need** - I need the twig or symfony class to edit the main `render()` method but I can't find the right File. OR: Anyone have an idea which is better to solve this problem.

Comment: What is your problem?
What did you want to achieve? Where do you want to call this function?

Comment: the symfony render method dont see this value. Thatswhy im looking for a way to inject the path into the render method directly but i dont found the correct method (i found 8 render() methods and nothing is working). There are no changes after change a render method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The render funtion expects the following params:

```
/**
 * Renders a view.
 *
 * @param string   $view       The view name
 * @param array    $parameters An array of parameters to pass to the view
 * @param Response $response   A response instance
 *
 * @return Response A Response instance
 *
 * @final since version 3.4
 */
```

So as long as you pass the correct view name: `@BUNDLE_NAME:RESOURCE_NAME_FOLDER:TWIG_FILE` then you should be good to go.

UPDATE:

I think I understand what you need after you provided more details. As no example was provided I will try to work with realistic scenario.

Imagine you have 2 templates, blue and red, they have structure and color differences but the content is mostly the same. I would then have 2 directories under my template folder.

```
/app
  /Resources
    /views
      /blue
        base_template.html.twig
      /red
        base_template.html.twig (they can have different names it doesn't really matter)
```

each one would define a `base_template` where you set your imports and other specifics of the template.

Now on you controller you get the `base_template` value from the DB as your function already does.

Then in your controller, you can use that value and pass it to your template that will extend it dynamically.

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('AppBundle:Home:index.html.twig',["base_template"=>loadTpl()]);
    }
```

Finally in your twig file you would extend the template like this:

```
{% extends base_template %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    My content
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is a link to : [Twig Dynamic Inheritance](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html#dynamic-inheritance)

Comment: Ok, but then i need to check in every Controller the actual template, right? Its not possible to use $this->render('settings/basicsettings.html.twig') and the path is (dashboard/settings/.....)?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you get from the DB ? If the path is relative to the bundle then you can hard code the @Bundle_name and get the template name from the DB

Comment: I get the name (dashboard) by the example template. If i edit the template path in twig.yaml it works fine. But i wish a dynamic solution when i Change the active template in database.

Comment: @DanielRichter  I’m sorry but I can’t understand your problem. Please provide a complete example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i have edited my question, hope u can follow my ideas now

Comment: @DanielRichter please check my update and let me know if that answers your question

Comment: Exactly thats what i want. Many thanks. It can be so simple... Thanks :)